# Mongoose + Node.js : Async issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I have a bunch of profiles in my ReadyForReview collection. Each profile contains a 'user_id_to_review' field. I want to use user_id_to_review to append the user's information from the Users collection to each profile.

```
// looking for all ReadyForReview profiles
ReadyForReview.find()
.exec(function(err, profilesReadyForReview) {
    var profilesReadyForReviewArray = [] //array that will be populated with profiles and user info

    // for each profile, figure out what the info for the user is from user table
    for (var i = 0; i < profilesReadyForReview.length; i++) {
        var thisUserProfile = profilesReadyForReview[i].user_id_to_review.toObjectId() // create objectID version of user_id_to_review
        User.find({
                '_id': thisUserProfile
            })
            .exec(function(err, user_whose_profile_it_is) {
                profilesReadyForReviewArray.push({
                    profile: profilesReadyForReview[i],
                    user: user_whose_profile_it_is
                })
            })
        console.dir(profilesReadyforReviewArray) // should be an array of profiles and user info
    }

})
```

However, *i* in the User.find function is wrong due to async. How can I achieve an array of profiles and user information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the async library to do your loops. 
https://github.com/caolan/async

```
// looking for all ReadyForReview profiles
ReadyForReview.find()
.exec(function(err, profilesReadyForReview) {
    var profilesReadyForReviewArray = [] //array that will be populated with profiles and user info

    // for each profile, figure out what the info for the user is from user table
    async.each(profilesprofilesReadyForReview, function(profile, done) {
        var profileId = profile.user_id_to_review.toObjectId() // create objectID version of user_id_to_review
        User.find({
                '_id': profileId
            })
            .exec(function(err, user_whose_profile_it_is) {
                profilesReadyForReviewArray.push({
                    profile: profile,
                    user: user_whose_profile_it_is
                })
                done();
            });
        }, function(){
            console.dir(profilesReadyforReviewArray) // should be an array of profiles and user info
        });
});
```

Comment: I think you're correct here but that reference to `profilesReadyForReview[i]` should probably be just `profile`

Comment: Works! Thanks to you both! May the code Gods shine brightly on your day.